# How to print Database value as we input in Drupal 7 or PHP?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Below is the input I gave in textarea.

---

```
Hi Ram,

How are you?

Thank you.
```

---

When hit submit it got stored in Database.

Below is the value when I get back from Database and print

---

```
Hi Ram,How are you?Thank you.
```

---

Here is the Issue. When I get from Database I want to pint same as input.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ................ `nl2br()`

Comment: Is there any way to Paste the "images with text" in textarea and get stored in Database read same as we input?

Comment: There are certain modules for that. You need to search on Drupal.org

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

I think you should consider using [WYSIWYG module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg). The usage of this module and some libraries (such as CKEditor) provides a user-friendly interface to add styles to your textareas. Roughly speaking, it provides bold, italic, link, images and many other features.

[image]

This is an example of what you will see editing a textarea with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Here my requirement is Copy mail content(Combination of images and text ) and paste in textarea and store this in database table. In other page I need to get this value back and show as we input.

Comment: In creditor I can upload an image but not able to paste.